# Can't install Kali on a USB 3.0 SSD

Tags: installation, ssd, kali-linux, usb-3

I bought a USB 3.0 SSD to install Kali on it for a high performance external boot setup. Unfortunately, I can't select my USB SSD in the installation process. I tried it on my laptop, but also via a VM. Both without success.

I tried different BIOS options on my laptop but it didn't make any difference. In the past I installed Kali on a USB 3.0 stick without problems (installation where I booted from a usb stick and installed Kali on another USB stick).

I really have no clue what is causing the problem with the SSD. Is there any superuser with experience in this field?

Comment: Are there any errors messages at all?